# Constraint Set problem, Unable to figure out issue

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraintset, dynamiclayout

I have extended ConstraintLayout and adding views programatically then setting constraint to each view. but some how its not working, only the first view is showing up. Unable to figure out where I went wrong.

```
addViews(){
        titleInfoView = new TextView(getContext());
        titleInfoView.setId(ViewCompat.generateViewId());
        addView(titleInfoView);

        editBoxView = new EditText(contextWrapper);
        editBoxView.setId(ViewCompat.generateViewId());
        addView(editBoxView);

        notInfoView = new TextView(getContext());
        notInfoView.setId(ViewCompat.generateViewId());
        addView(notInfoView);
    
        errorMessageView = new TextView(getContext());
        errorMessageView.setId(ViewCompat.generateViewId());
        addView(errorMessageView);

}
```

Then adding constraint to each view

```
 private void addConstraintToViews() {
     
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        set.clone(this);

        //connect title view
        set.connect(titleInfoView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP);
        set.connect(titleInfoView.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START);
        set.connect(titleInfoView.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END);


        //connect edit box
        set.connect(editBoxView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, titleInfoView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.dimen.margin_10);
        set.connect(editBoxView.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START);
        set.connect(editBoxView.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END);

        //connect info title
        set.connect(notInfoView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, editBoxView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.dimen.margin_10);
        set.connect(notInfoView.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START);
        set.connect(notInfoView.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END);

        //connect error messag
        set.connect(errorMessageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, notInfoView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, R.dimen.margin_10);
        set.connect(errorMessageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START);
        set.connect(errorMessageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END);
        set.connect(errorMessageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);

        set.applyTo(this);
    }
```

Only First item is showing up that is Title like this image. I want to add each view one after another and that how i wrote the constraintset. Can any one suggest what is getting wrong.
[image]

Comment: Try setting [LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) to the `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally Figure out the issue. I was properly setting layout param for each widget but when I was setting constraint to each widget under Parent constraint layout, I am adding margin at the end.

This seems to be issue, might be some bug on Constraint Layout. Just removed that margin now the views are displayed.